# CSS Error parsing ( Expected LBRACE at [1,9] )

Tags: javafx

My css has the following error code.

> CSS Error parsing file:/C:/Users/dsm/Desktop/efxclipse/workspace/style/css/a.css: Expected LBRACE at [1,9]

I searched the Internet for an answer, and it says, at line 1,  col 9  I am missing left brace { .  However, if you look at my code line 1. I don't know where to put {.  Can anyone have any advice?

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8"; //this is my code line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaFX cannot parse this line and will throw an exception.**

You should only use `@charset` if style sheet and the HTML-file, that is calling the style sheet, have different encodings.

If a parser has problems with this line, it should be save to omit it - as long as your files are encoded correctly in UTF-8.